# Align pieces of text onto the same line

Tags: html, css, css-float, text-alignment

```
        <article id='Focus'>
            <h1 id='main'>Focus</h1>
                <article id='Tell'>
                    <h1>Tell</h1>

                </article>
                <article id='NStart'>
                    <h1>NStart</h1>
                </article>
                <article id='FSB'>
                    <h1>pppp</h1>
                </article>
        </article>
```

I have this html code and I want to make it so that its all aligned on the same line, with one positioned left, another in the centre and the other on the right.
I have tried using float and text-align but these don't work. What CSS should I be looking at to make this work?

Comment: It's not clear why you are using this odd HTML structure or what you have tried so far. Can you provide your CSS? A JSfiddle would be useful.

Comment: So the left, center and right parts are the articles, correct?  Note that when you use `float` you must also consider the `clear` property.

Comment: I thought article is new html 5 syntax?

Comment: yes they are, sorry should have made that clear

Comment: `<article` is allowed under HTML5 but your wrapping element should, i suspect be a `<section>`

Comment: this is only part of my html code which is why it might look like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this solution be good for you? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hf3Za/4/)

Html

```
<article id='Focus'>
    <h1 id='main'>Focus</h1>
    <br/>
    <article id='Tell'>
         <h1>Tell</h1>
    </article>
    <article id='NStart'>
         <h1>NStart</h1>
    </article>
    <article id='FSB'>
         <h1>pppp</h1>
    </article>
</article>
```

CSS

```
article {
    width:33%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
#Focus {
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **CSS:**

```
#Focus article {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tou can use this css:

```
#Focus article {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R6ES8/)